# Metro Bundler fails while trying to resolve module `immer` from redux-toolkit

Tags: expo, redux-toolkit, metro-bundler, immer.js, expo-go

I'm building a react native app using Expo and Expo Go to test it on an android device. It has been working flawlessly until today. I encoutered an error on one of my components with this kind of error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable(android.content.res.Resources)' on a null object reference
```

Solution seemed to me to clear cache `yarn cache clean`. I also cleared cache on the Expo Go app. But this led me to Metro Bundler failing with this error:

```
Android Bundling failed 1279ms
While trying to resolve module `immer` from file `H:\my_project\app\node_modules\@reduxjs\toolkit\dist\redux-toolkit.cjs.production.min.js`, the package `H:\my_project\app\node_modules\immer\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`H:\my_project\app\node_modules\immer\dist\immer.esm.mjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * H:\my_project\app\node_modules\immer\dist\immer.esm.mjs(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  * H:\my_project\app\node_modules\immer\dist\immer.esm.mjs\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
```

When checking `H:\my_project\app\node_modules\immer\dist\`, I do find an `immer.esm.mjs` file but no `H:\my_project\app\node_modules\immer\dist\immer.esm.mjs\` folder with an `index` file in it.

So I tried to manually remove `node_modules/` and reinstall packages with `yarn`, restart the Expo server, doing all this after restarting my machine, even ran `expo upgrade`, removed `.expo/`, removed `yarn.lock`, but I keep getting the same error.

This leaves me quite confused. Thank you for your suggestions on what to do.

---

Here are the dependencies versions used as in my `package.json`:

```
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.1",
"@types/react-redux": "^7.1.22",
"expo": "~45.0.0",
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.68.2",
"react-redux": "8.0.1",
"redux": "4.2.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fix**

As suggested in [this redux-toolkit issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2315), there seems to be an issue with `immer` version  `9.0.13`. Temporary fix suggested there is working for me, adding `immer@9.0.12` to my resolutions in `packages.json`:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "immer": "9.0.12"
  }
```

---

**Update**

This [PR on immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer/pull/939) resolved this issue (`9.0.14`). I can confirm the above fix isn't needed anymore on my side. Looks like my bad luck came from some breaking changes being pushed on a minor release.

Comment: Weird, I'm getting this error on `10.0.2` now :/

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle Did you try to add `.mjs` extension to `resolver.sourceExts` array as stated here: https://github.com/immerjs/immer/issues/1065#issuecomment-1709508198 ?
Issue: https://github.com/immerjs/immer/issues/1058

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle Also, you'd want to check this commit https://github.com/immerjs/immer/commit/b860730ead52ffbc99e82a9032cc483f79eb9734

Comment: Yeah that `.mjs` extension add did the trick!